# what to do if I found a fraudulent wallet?

Tags: fraud

I was scammed via bitcoin and the scammers' wallet is currently holding 98 stolen bitcoins (from several victims). the amount is unspent in the current wallet . is there anything to do? I went to the police but can I report the wallet some ware ? Write to anyone ? Find out in what exchange does the wallet sit?

This is the hash of the fraud wallet : 115906bc83bebc7511a2c497961e87e7fc3783b2ae5645e4605f9adad4571847

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can bitcoins be traced to scammers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83197/can-bitcoins-be-traced-to-scammers) or [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91943/13866) or see other [questions about tracing addresses, wallets, scammers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=trace)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the transactions linked to the 36Nq2uXqCaXu5kTN3mZtRubqHiVsYbQsMN address, the smaller transactions in look like they have come from a mixing service (equal amount batch transactions). The fact the address has not sent any funds limits the inferences which can be drawn. I'd suggest waiting until there is sending activity from the address and then see what that brings out as new information to pursue the matter further.  Reporting the matter to the police is a start, just a case of watching to see what happens next.

Do not visit the site outlined in the link posted, no one can get your coins back unless the recipient wants to give them back. This is even the way it works if you report it to authorities, they try to find out who the recipient is and then make them give back the coins. The company in the link will only ask for money up front and then fail to deliver anything.

Answer (score -1):

> is there anything to do?

No

> I went to the police but can I report the wallet [somewhere] ?

You can

> Write to anyone ?

Whatever you want

> Find out in what exchange does the wallet sit?

Impossible with your skills

Transaction: [115906bc83bebc7511a2c497961e87e7fc3783b2ae5645e4605f9adad4571847](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/115906bc83bebc7511a2c497961e87e7fc3783b2ae5645e4605f9adad4571847)

Address: [36Nq2uXqCaXu5kTN3mZtRubqHiVsYbQsMN](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/36Nq2uXqCaXu5kTN3mZtRubqHiVsYbQsMN)

Comment: what skills do I need to find out the exchange ? if its indeed possible ...