# Is it possible to recover stolen funds from the scammers wallet?

Tags: fraud, binance, bitfinex, tether

Im a victim of a bitcoin scam.
The scammers gave me a fake wallet address and stole all my USDT.
Since im new here im trying to increase my reputation to be able to comment and ask questions to specific users.
Im looking for blockchain experts to help me with my situation.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91943/13866). or [Can bitcoins be traced to scammers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/83197/13866)

Comment: yes, it does. thank you very much for your help